# Bundler could not find compatible versions of gem "rspec-mocks" - Bundler::VersionConflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, bundler, rspec-mocks

I try to deploy on a hosters server. But when I go to my domain, I see phusion passengers error messages:

```
Could not find gem 'guard-rspec (= 2.5.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

So I do:

```
$ gem install rspec-rails -v 2.13.1
```

Then I get:

```
Could not find gem 'rspec-rails (= 2.13.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

SO I do again:

```
$ gem install guard-rspec -v 2.5.0
```

And finally I get this:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rspec-mocks":
  In Gemfile:
    guard-rspec (= 2.5.0) ruby depends on
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0) ruby

```
rspec-rails (= 2.13.1) ruby depends on
  rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
```

(Bundler::VersionConflict)

DO I have to delete one of them from my Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you specify your gems in your Gemfile along with their required versions and have bundle install it rather than doing it directly in the system.

Gemfile:

```
gem "guard-rspec", "2.5.0"
gem ....
```

Then install the gems

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

Also worth a try to do:

```
bundle upgrade
```

Comment: I think you mean bundle update... Tread very carefully when doing this! A lot can go wrong.... YMMV.